# Add a string to the ajax responseText

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to add a string to my ajax responseText string. I have checked and yes the responseText is a string but nothing changes when i try to add some additional text to the string. My js:

```js
function ajax(instruction, push, url, callback) {

  var xmlhttp; // the object for the httprequest

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) { // status 200 = sucessfull page! NOT 404!  // 1 2 3 4 are states of the request (4 is when it's done)

      //console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);

      xmlhttp.responseText = xmlhttp.responseText + "<script>resize();</script>";
      console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
      callback(xmlhttp);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open(instruction, url, true); // sends a the var q to the next php file
  xmlhttp.send(''); // Sends the request

  if (push == true) { // Change the link to the url of the ajax with

    var newLink = "?p=" + url; // Gives us the link we want except that we don't want the .php

    newLink = newLink.substring(0, newLink.indexOf('.')); // makes a new string with character 0 to the dot

    var urlPath = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
    window.history.pushState({
      path: urlPath
    }, '', newLink);

  } else {}

}
```

```html
<a href='' onclick="if(useAjax == true){ ajax('GET', true, 'home.php', function(xmlhttp){ document.getElementById('content_holder').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; }); return false;}">Home</a>
```

The code snippet dosn't work here by some reason, but it all works for me execept that nothing happens with the response text when this is executed:

```
xmlhttp.responseText = xmlhttp.responseText + "<script>resize();</script>";
```

Comment: That's a read-only property.  Don't do that.

Comment: You should use a different variable to append your text. Don't append to your xhr response text.

Comment: Thanks guys I have actually never heard of that but it works now. Should i remove this post?